# batch execution is blocked when launched using subprocess.run

Tags: python, eclipse, batch-file, subprocess

I have the following batch which I use to launch eclipse/tasking to generate makefiles for my C project:

*test_eclipsec.bat*

```
echo off

set my_eclipse=C:\Program Files\TASKING\TriCore v6.3r1\ctc\eclipse
set my_workspace=C:\Users\firsname.name\Desktop\Repositories\PF_SW
set my_project=xxx
set my_project_config=Release

echo Generating Makefiles
"%my_eclipse%\eclipsec.exe" -nosplash -application com.tasking.managedbuilder.headlessbuild -data %my_workspace% -generateMakefile %my_project%/%my_project_config%
echo Generating Makefiles end
```

By itself, this script works well.

But I want this batch script to be launched from my Python script.
So in my Python script, I call the following function:

```
    def generate_makefile(self):
        batch_path = Path("msw/support/build/test_eclipsec.bat")
        subprocess.run(batch_path)
```

The python script prints the following line:

> Generating Makefiles

Which is an echo in my batch script.
But then the Python script is blocked. It does not anything else (it should), and I have to manually stop the execution of my Python script.
It seems that it gets stuck on the execution of eclipse.

I also tried to run the eclipse cmd line directly from python by using subprocess.run(). But it gets stuck as well.

I don't know how to resolve this issue.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It was the console of my IDE (Pycharm) which did not handle the subprocess (still don't know why). I changed a few settings in Pycharm (Emulate terminal in output console) and now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

`subprocess.run` is a blocking call. It waits for your command to complete, then returns a `CompletedProcess` instance. Are you sure you waited long enough for your build command to complete?

Comment: Yes I am waiting long enough. When I launch the batch script from windows explorer, or from a command prompt, it takes only a few second to complete.